Как загрузить дом и функцию до промпт?
Я хочу что бы запустился промпт не прерывая таймер, то есть сперва загрузив все остальное. Если вы мне и хтмл ошибки найдете будет хорошо. Вот html:
<div class="container">
    <h1>Bomb Game</h1>
    <div class="timer">
    
        <p id="time">Timer: <br>
            00:00</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="pass">
        <p id="password">Пароль:<br>
            0--0--0</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="index.js"></script>

А здесь JavaScript:
var time = 59.99;

var stop = setInterval(function Boom(){    
    time -=0.01;
    time = Math.floor(time * 100) / 100;
    document.getElementById("time").textContent = 
      `Time: ${time}`;

if(time === 0){
    clearInterval(stop);
   }
}, 10);


const num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
alert(num1);

const num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
alert(num2);

const num3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
alert(num3);

document.getElementById("password").textContent = 
`Password: ${a}--${b}--${c}`

let inp1 = Number(prompt("Enter num1"));

while(inp1 = "" || inp1 == null || inp1 != num1){
    inp1 = window.prompt("Enter your inp1");
}

let inp2 = Number(prompt("Ennter num2"));

while(inp2 = "" || inp2 == null || inp2 != num2){
    inp2 = window.prompt("Enter your inp2");
}

let inp3 = Number(prompt("Enter num3"));

while(inp3 = "" || inp3 == null || inp3 != num3){
    inp3 = window.prompt("Enter your inp3");
}

Опять же я сделал alert и хотел их заменить (ответы)
что бы знать ответы, пока не решу проблему ну как я понял надо создать свое окно,
Если надо ещё что то скажите,  я очень хочу научиться программированию и если вы сможете облегчить или исправить ошибки я буду очень благодарен

добавь [mcve] который можно запустить и увидеть твою проблему. сейчас по объяснениям непонятно что ты делаешь и что хочешь получить

Добавьте в вопрос вашу разметку html и весь js код, про который идет речь в вопросе, что бы можно было воспроизвести проблему

Вот 像插頭一樣愚蠢 я хочу запустить промпт не останавливая таймер. получается я должен создать свое модальное окно ?!

да, все стандартные диалоги останавливают выполнение всех скриптов. Поэтому тебе самому нужно реализовать элемент для ввода - можешь просто input добавить в свою разметку

Ок, Спасибо большое
